# Low Graphics and laggy screen after update to 13.10 from 13.04

Tags: ati, 13.10, hybrid-graphics

After updating from 13.04 to 13.10 many of 3D unity stuff has stopped working,

I am suing Samsung Series 3 (NP350V5X) Laptop which has Switchable Intel and AMD Radeon HD 7670M GFX.

1. **xserver-xorg-video-ati** does works but NO 3D support and graphics are very low. [I am currently using this]
2. **fglrx** & **fglrx-updates** shows blank screen after Login.
3. Intel Graphic Install doesn't work either (dependency error)

Output of $ **sudo lshw -c video**

```
  *-display               
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Thames [Radeon HD 7500M/7600M Series]
       vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: 00
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm pciexpress msi vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=radeon latency=0
       resources: irq:45 memory:e0000000-efffffff memory:c0120000-c013ffff ioport:3000(size=256) memory:c0100000-c011ffff
  *-display
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 09
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:46 memory:bfc00000-bfffffff memory:d0000000-dfffffff ioport:4000(size=64)
```

Similarly $ **/usr/lib/nux/unity_support_test -p**

```
OpenGL vendor string:   VMware, Inc.
OpenGL renderer string: Gallium 0.4 on llvmpipe (LLVM 3.3, 256 bits)
OpenGL version string:  2.1 Mesa 9.2.1


Not software rendered:    no
Not blacklisted:          yes
GLX fbconfig:             yes
GLX texture from pixmap:  yes
GL npot or rect textures: yes
GL vertex program:        yes
GL fragment program:      yes
GL vertex buffer object:  yes
GL framebuffer object:    yes
GL version is 1.4+:       yes


Unity 3D supported:       no
```

Shows no 3D support.

Can anyone please guide how to make things working again.

**Update**: Issue fixed now, after updating to latest Ubuntu Binary for ATI. (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/ATI)

Output of $ /**usr/lib/nux/unity_support_test -p** is,

```
OpenGL vendor string:   ATI Technologies Inc.
OpenGL renderer string: AMD Radeon HD 7600M Series
OpenGL version string:  4.2.12337 Compatibility Profile Context 13.101

Not software rendered:    yes
Not blacklisted:          yes
GLX fbconfig:             yes
GLX texture from pixmap:  yes
GL npot or rect textures: yes
GL vertex program:        yes
GL fragment program:      yes
GL vertex buffer object:  yes
GL framebuffer object:    yes
GL version is 1.4+:       yes

Unity 3D supported:       yes
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the same issue.  Using `lshw`

```
  *-display:0             
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: RV350 [Radeon 9550]
       vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: 00
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 66MHz
       capabilities: agp agp-2.0 pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=radeon latency=32 mingnt=8
       resources: irq:16 memory:e0000000-efffffff ioport:c800(size=256) memory:ff8f0000-ff8fffff memory:ff8c0000-ff8dffff
  *-display:1 UNCLAIMED
       description: Display controller
       product: RV350 [Radeon 9550] (Secondary)
       vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
       physical id: 0.1
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.1
       version: 00
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 66MHz
       capabilities: pm bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=32 mingnt=8
       resources: memory:d0000000-dfffffff memory:ff8e0000-ff8effff
```

I tried using mesa 10.0 with no impact.

Answer (score 0):

After installing the proprietary fglrx driver you have to generate a fresh xorg.conf **BEFORE REBOOTING!** you have to run:

**$sudo aticonfig --initial**

If you already installed the drivers and rebooted getting a blank screen after login, press CTRL+ALT+F1, login, run the command from that console and reboot.

I recommend you read the full ubuntu help wiki on the subject:

[BinaryDriverHowto/ATI](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/ATI)

Hope that helps!